# Iterate through 2 dimensional array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

```
for(int k=0;k <= odds.GetLength(-1);k++)
```

The above line of code is supposed to iterate through a two dimensional array of type Double but keeps throwing the following exception. Index Out Of Range Exception. Would someone be kind enough to explain why and provide a solution. Many thanks.

Comment: Are you changing the contents of 'odds' at any point in the loop?

Comment: Yes in the following way 'code'win +=  odds[ 1,k]*unitStake; 'code'

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You are passing an invalid index to [`GetLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx). The dimensions of a multidimensional array are `0` based, so `-1` is invalid and using a negative number (or a number that is larger than the number of dimensions - 1) would cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

This will loop over the *first* dimension:

```
for (int k = 0; k < odds.GetLength(0); k++)
```

You need to add another loop to go through the second dimension:

```
for (int k = 0; k < odds.GetLength(0); k++)
    for (int l = 0; l < odds.GetLength(1); l++)
        var val = odds[k, l];
```

Comment: the conditional part of the loops should specify '<' instead of '<=' or you will get out of index exception.

Comment: @John - thanks. You could have suggested that edit directly though :)

Answer (score 17):

Well, usualy when you want to iterate on a 2D array:

```
for(int col = 0; col < arr.GetLength(0); col++)
    for(int row = 0; row < arr.GetLength(1); row++)
        arr[col,row] =  /*something*/;
```

Arrays are always zero-based, so there's no point of trying to get something at -1 index.

Answer (score 10):

```
string[,] arr = new string[2, 3];
        arr[0, 0] = "0,0";
        arr[0, 1] = "0,1";
        arr[0, 2] = "0,2";

        arr[1, 0] = "1,0";
        arr[1, 1] = "1,1";
        arr[1, 2] = "1,2";

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Response.Write(string.Format("{0}\t", arr[i, j]));
            }
            Response.Write("<br/>");
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

If `odds` is a two-dimensional array, then its dimensions will be called `0` and `1`. Trying to access dimension `-1` will yield an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 3):

`GetLength` is zero-based. Try calling `GetLength(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

I see one or two problems depending on how you intend to use it:

First off, GetLength(ind dimension) returns length of specified dimension, starting from 0. In case of a two-dimensional array, correct indices would be 0 and 1.

The second problem is that you are doing <= instead of < for loop condition, which might also go out of bounds since last index is length-1 and not length.

StriplingWarrior and Gilad Naaman posted code examples so I'll skip that.

Answer (score -1):

I followed the accepted answer but it throw exception in my code.

This is my way to iterate 2 dimension array using 2 foreach loop.
I share for whom concerned.

```
int i = 0;
      
foreach (var innercell in cells)
{
    int j = 0;
    foreach (var item in innercell)
    {
       if (j == cell.Col && cell.Row == i)
       {
         item.TagName = cell.TagName;
         item.Text = cell.Text;
         exist = true;
         break;
        }
        j++;
     }
     i++;
}
```

Comment: Also threw an error for me about "out of bounds" when trying `GetLength(1)`. Turns out this does not work if the 2D array is a *jagged* array. If that's the case you can use `my2dArray[0].Length`, assuming that there is no array with a different number of columns.

Answer (score -1):

The following code will iterate over the 2 Dimensional array named arr and will calculate the sum of all its elements.

```
int sum =0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (arr[i]).Length; j++)
        {
            sum+=(arr[i][j]);
        }
     }
```

Comment: That is NOT a 2-dimensional array. What you have in your code is a jagged array.

Comment: The OP also said that the type of the array was `double`.