# Save the sum of each row of a matrix into an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a matrix and I want to return an array containing as elements the sum of each row elements of the matrix.

```
int [] sum;

for (var i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < result.Pages[i].Actual.Count; j++)
    {
        sum[i] += result.Pages[i].Actual[j];
    }

}
```

This is how I tried to do it but seems it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: you can simply get the length of each array dimension and use that to determine how many times to loop. https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&ei=iJ8uWvPUIcrawAKSyq-ICA&q=c%23+array+length+multidimensional&oq=C%23+array+length&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i71k1l4.0.0.0.127072.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.RCt0FhDJbqc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through 2 dimensional array c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184306/iterate-through-2-dimensional-array-c-sharp)

Comment: @MongZhu I had edited it

Comment: what is `Pages` ? a `List` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now that looks like a different story after you edit:

Actually the first problem would be a `NullreferenceException` because `int[]sum` is not initialized!

Anyway, so it seems that you have an array of arrays. In this case you would need the `Length` of the `Pages` array to save your results. The first loop iterates over it using `i` and will run until `result.Pages.Length`. For each `i` you have correctly implemented a second loop where you sum up the result.

```
int [] sum = new int[result.Pages.Length];

for (var i = 0; i < result.Pages.Length; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < result.Pages[i].Actual.Length; j++)
    {
        sum[i] += result.Pages[i].Actual[j];
    }    
}
```

If you collections are `List`'s then you need to use `Count` instead of `Length`

The Linq solution would look like this:

```
int [] sum = result.Pages.Select(x=>x.Sum()).ToArray();
```

EDIT:

`double?` means that you have a nullable data type. This is different from the normal `double`. Furthermore the default value will be `null` That means that you need to initialize the value at position `i` in `sum` before you add up values, otherwise the result will be `null`.

```
double? [] sum = new double?[result.Pages.Length];

for (var i = 0; i < result.Pages.Length; i++)
{
    sum[i] = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < result.Pages[i].Actual.Length; j++)
    {
        sum[i] += result.Pages[i].Actual[j];
    }    
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it seems clear now. I only have one issue, the data is in `double?` format or that the error I'm get. I changed sum from `int` to `double` but still now effect

Comment: @user3654571 "or that the error I'm get. " I don't see any error... does it have an error message? you really should post the code that you are testing, otherwise we keep playing a guessing game

Comment: @user3654571 `double?` means that you have a nullable data type. This is different from the normal `double`. Furthermore the default value will be `null` That means that you need to change the initialize the value at position `i`

Answer (score 3):

Use `var m = a.GetLength(0);` to get number of rows, and `var n = a.GetLength(1);` to get number of columns.