# Get first element in each row of 2d array

Tags: c#, for-loop

How do you iterate through a 2d array and get the first element in each row? For example:

```
int[,] array = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12} };
```

desired output: 1 4 7 10

Comment: Using for loop; have you tried with it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through 2 dimensional array c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184306/iterate-through-2-dimensional-array-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
int[,] array = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12} };
for (int row = 0; row < array.GetLength(0); ++row)
{
    Console.WriteLine(array[row, 0]);
}
```

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/UDQJ26992)

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much, I was over thinking it way too much. Legend :)