# Write a program in C# which uses Iterative Binary Search algorithm to search age of the person using his / her name

Tags: c#, binary-search

This requires splitting the array which contains age and name of the person, and then performing search operation on the name variable and finally print the age if the name is present in the array.

So, far I have only created a 2D array but don't know how to split and then perform the search

```
String[,] arr = { { "aakif", "25" }, {"ali", "31"} , {"ben","35"}, {"hassnain" ,"45" } };
```

Comment: In this case of situation you're better off with a dictionary (key,value)

Comment: I have to use a 2D array, its part of an assignment task.

Comment: @Melchia I'm getting the feeling that ali_25 wants to learn how to do a binary search, and not just use a pre-packaged solution like `Dictionary`.

Comment: You're going to need to show some code that illustrates what you've done to solve the problem (and show it as text, not an image). A few things to note. C# is an object oriented language; you could define an object type (i.e., a `class`) that represents a Person with name and age properties, and then put instances of those objects in a singly dimensioned array. Also, the internet has search tools. The binary search algorithm is well known, and finding an example should not be too hard

Comment: Let's see what you tried.  Especially where you keep track of the `start` and `end` of the range that you are searching.  At some point you will calculate the `midpoint` between `start` and `end` and then update either `start` or `end` and assign it the value of `midpoint` to continue searching in either the first half or second half of the range.

Comment: Maybe not the rigth but I sugest to create an Person Object and use List<PersonObject>.

Comment: @Wyck I know how to do a binary search on 1D Arrays either by recursive method or iterative method. I just can't figure out how to do it on 2D arrays + search using only the first element in this case, the name of person .. and then print the second element in this case, the age if search is matched.

Comment: @Wyck I Will deal with that part..the start and end thing..but first how to split it and store the names in a separate search variable.

Comment: assuming https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-arrays-of-strings/ is wrong too, from standard C I would say that your array sizes are wrong and you need 2,4 !?

Comment: @B.Go oh right. I'll Correct it. Thanks

Comment: @DavidG I know its not. I can't find and example on internet related to my problem and I am quite stuck .. I have been doing this task for quite sometime ‍♂️but can't figure it out.

Comment: And asking here is not the right course of action, there are other sites better suited for these kinds of questions.

Comment: I don't understand your array. You initialize a 2x4 array, but then assign it to an array variable you declare as 1x3. And, your array has two names and two ages in the same chunk. Try putting one name and one age in each piece and the solution may become apparent. `var arr=new[,]={{"Bob", "25"},{"Jane","32"}, etc };`

Comment: @DavidG maybe you are right. Sorry for inconvenience. I Will delete the post before it causes much pain to others.

Comment: @Flydog57 yes there was a problem, I have corrected it.

Comment: The pain is all yours.  Those DVs stay with you even if you delete it.  I also dont buy that [there is no information on iterating a 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8184306/1070452) on the internet

Comment: Now change the array contents. If you consider the array as `row,column`, put one name and one age in each row (i.e., each row has a `name` column (column 0) and an `age` column (column 1)). The result is that each row represents a person. Now, since you say you know how to do a binary search, do your search over the set of rows; doing whatever you'd do to the rows as a whole

Comment: @Flydog57 thanks. I have completed the task with help ofcourse.

Comment: Your data looks 1-dimensional to me.  This would be obvious if you had a 1-dimensional array of structs rather than a two dimensional array of strings.  Unfortunately, with a 2-dimensional array of strings, all the columns of each row must the the same type.  In your case: string.  That's just not very flexible.  Especially since you are unable to represent those numbers as actual integers, and instead are storing everything as strings.    This really looks like a 1-dimensional search problem where the columns just happen to be in a 2d array because all fields are strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do disagree with the way you store your input but you can achieve your search with the following:

```
String[,] arr = new string[2,4];
arr[0, 0] = "saif";
arr[0, 1] = "25";
arr[0, 2] = "ali";
arr[0, 3] = "17";
arr[1, 0] = "aakif";
arr[1, 1] = "11";
arr[1, 2] = "hassnain";
arr[1, 3] = "50";

int index = -1;
int jindex = -1;
for ( int i =0 ; i <arr.GetLength(0) ; i++) {
    for ( int j =0 ; j <arr.GetLength(1) ; j++) {
        if (arr[i,j]== "ali")   {
            index = i;
            jindex = j;
            break;
        }

    }
}

if ( index != -1) {
    Console.WriteLine(arr[index,jindex] + " " + arr[index,jindex +1 ]);
}
else Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I have corrected the input storage way.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{

  static partial class Program
  {
```

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Test();
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("End.");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

```
    static void Test()
    {
      string[,] arr = 
      { 
        { "aakif", "25" }, 
        { "ali", "31" }, 
        { "ben", "35" }, 
        { "hassnain", "45" }
      };
      string search = "ali";
      string age = arr.GetAge(search);
      if ( age != null )
        Console.WriteLine($"{search} age = {age}");
      else
        Console.WriteLine($"{search} not found");
    }
```

```
    static string GetAge(this string[,] array, string name)
    {
      for ( int index = array.GetLowerBound(0); index <= array.GetUpperBound(0); index++ )
        if ( array[index, array.GetLowerBound(1)] == name )
          return array[index, array.GetUpperBound(1)];
      return null;
    }
```

```
  }

}
```

Output:

```
ali age = 31
```

Answer (score 0):

The first index of the index [0,0], [1,0] if the name you are looking for.  [Index, 1] and print the age value.

```
string[,] arr = { { "aakif", "25" }, { "ali", "31" }, { "ben", "35" }, { "hassnain", "45" } };
        string search = "ali";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (arr[i,0].ToString() == search)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i, 0] + " " + arr[i, 1] + " years old");
            }
        }
```