# Q: Looping through table elements and identifying through CSS styles (selenium webdriver in c#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table with elements that have no value, but different styles. I need to loop through them and select the first cell with no style whatsoever. How can I go about this?

I tried with using CSS selectors but to no avail because I couldn't find other possibilities. The class for all elements is the same. The unique identifier I found were the ones called 'startdate' but that needs hard-coding (which I don't plan on using in the long run).

Sharing below the code I have:

```
var elemTable = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//*[@id='gantt']//*[@id='rhtblock']//*[@id='gridrhtbot']));
List<IWebElement> lstTrElem = new List<IWebElement>(elemTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));
foreach(var elemTr in lstTrElem)
{
List<IWebElement> lstTdElem = new List<IwebElement>(elemTr.FindElements(By.TagName("td")));
if(lstTdElem.Count>0)
{
foreach (IWebElement elemTd in lstTdElem)
{ //nothing at this point//
}
```

This is where I'm stuck right now and can't progress any further.

HTML code below:

[image]

Also showing a sample of how the table looks:

|  | 00 | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Delivery |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Area 1 | (red line top border) | (filled grey cell) | (filled green cell) | (filled green cell) | (filled green cell) | (filled green cell) |
| Area 2 | (filled green cell) | (filled green cell) | (filled green cell) | (red line top border) | (red line top border) | (filled green cell) |
| Area 3 | (filled grey cell) | (filled grey cell) | (filled grey cell) | (red line top border) | (red line top border) | (filled grey cell) |

Hoping for any feedback or answers. Fingers crossed the details, codes, and tables can be of help too.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You may like to consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all cells row by row (see [Iterate through 2 dimensional array c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184306/iterate-through-2-dimensional-array-c-sharp)).

Rows and columns count is easy to get with `FindElements(..).Count()`.

And to access the specific cell - use XPath with indexes like `//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]`.